# Calculating Letter Grades From Numeric Values In Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column in MS Access that contains course grade information for students. I am trying to calculate a letter grade in another column based on the contents of the grade column.

Below is what I have so far:

```
IIf([Grade]>92.5,"A",

IIf([Grade]>89.5,IIf([Grade]<92.5,"A-",

IIf([Grade]>86.5,IIf([Grade]<89.5,"B+",

IIf([Grade]>82.5,IIf([Grade]<86.5,"B",

IIf([Grade]>79.5,IIf([Grade]<82.5,"B",

IIf([Grade]>69.5,IIf([Grade]<79.5,"C",

IIf([Grade]<69.5,"F"))))))))))))
```

This works as intended for "A" and "A-" but all the other course grades come out as blanks.

Here is the "A" and "A-" working alone:

```
IIf([Grade]>92.5,"A",IIf([Grade]>89.5,IIf([Grade]<92.5,"A-")))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create another table with the grades in it, and the upper and lower score boundaries.  Then you can just join on that lookup table.  *(For your `IIF` based approach, you don't need to check the upper boundaries twice.  If a score is greater than `92.5` it will already have been assigned to `A`...)*  `IIF([grade]>92.5, "A", IIF([grade]>89.5, "A-", IIF([grade]>86.5, "B+", <more_nested_IIFs>)))`

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: No, because it's a bad solution ;)  The lookup table is preferable for more reasons than I can type...

Comment: Hahahaha fair enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that in your nested `IIF`, you placed the low end first and then the high end second. Simply reverse and you output all matching letters but miss out on 0.5 endpoints.

```
IIf([Grade]>92.5,"A",

IIf([Grade]<92.5, IIf([Grade]>89.5,"A-",

IIf([Grade]<89.5, IIf([Grade]>86.5,"B+",

IIf([Grade]<86.5, IIf([Grade]>82.5,"B",

IIf([Grade]<82.5, IIf([Grade]>79.5,"B-",

IIf([Grade]<79.5, IIf([Grade]>69.5,"C",

IIf([Grade]<69.5,"F")))))))))))) As Letter
```

Alternatively, with less `IIF` use `BETWEEN` or `> AND <`. And since `BETWEEN` includes both end points and to be exhaustive, consider adding `.49999999`.

```
IIf([Grade]>92.5,"A",    
    IIf([Grade] BETWEEN 89.5 AND 92.49999999,"A-",    
        IIf([Grade] BETWEEN 86.5 AND 89.49999999,"B+",    
            IIf([Grade] BETWEEN 82.5 AND 86.49999999,"B",    
                IIf([Grade] BETWEEN 79.5 AND 82.49999999,"B-",    
                    IIf([Grade] BETWEEN 69.5 AND 79.49999999,"C",    
                        IIf([Grade] <= 69.49999999,"F", NULL))))))) As Letter2,
```

But even then only the high points with `>` are needed since you nest all conditions together.

```
IIf([Grade]>92.5,"A",
    IIf([Grade] > 89.5,"A-",
       IIf([Grade] > 86.5,"B+",
          IIf([Grade] > 82.5,"B",
             IIf([Grade] > 79.5,"B-",
                IIf([Grade] > 69.5,"C",
                    IIf([Grade]<=69.5,"F", NULL))))))) As Letter3
```

However, as @MatBailie suggests, consider a lookup table and run a range join query (with comma separated tables without any `JOIN`) then filter by values. Consider even incorporating above 100 (for extra credit) and below zero with room to actually hit 0.5 endpoints. This also provides better maintenance in case you adjust grade points.

*GradeLetter* table

```
ID  Letter  MinValue      MaxValue
1   A           92.5          1000
2   A-          89.5    92.4999999
3   B+          86.5    89.4999999
4   B           82.5    86.4999999
5   B-          79.5    82.4999999
6   C           69.5    79.4999999
7   F          -1000    69.4999999
```

Range Join Query

```
SELECT l.Letter, g.Grade
FROM Grades g, GradeLetter l
WHERE g.Grade 
BETWEEN l.MinValue AND l.MaxValue;
```

Comment: The < in the IIF version should be <=

Comment: The table based version would normally be >= min AND < max. This allows the boundaries to be exact values rather than limited by the precision of the data type.

Answer (score 4):

could be that using `Switch` is a bit more simple eg

```
SELECT
    Switch(
        [Grade]>92.5,"A",
        [Grade]>=89.5, "A-",
        [Grade]>=86.5, "B+",
        [Grade]>=82.5, "B",
        [Grade]>=79.5, "B",
        [Grade]>=69.5, "C",
        [Grade]<69.5, "F") AS my_grade
FROM my_table
```

Comment: The `AND` clauses are unnecessary because `Switch` will return the value for the first matching expression. It also helps avoid "missing" values, e.g., what if Grade is exactly 92.5?

Comment: @GordThompson   . correct  .. answer  updated  without unuseful AND   .. and added  >=  many thanks